# How can we do this via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

We need to display the data from a wordpress install on a current page.  Example would be:
This page:
http://www.example.com/facts/index.php

needs to display the content from this page:
http://www.example.com/news/new-facts/index.php

How can we do this via .htaccess?

Comment: I don't think this can be solved via .htaccess. You want to display a portion of a WP page in some other page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/facts/(.*)$ /news/new-facts/$1
```

Not sure if WordPress would accept that.